# REGEXP_SUBSTR function in stored procedure returns null

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following string:
`'AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23'`

I would like to return: `'CCC|1.23'`

When using the regexp: `\w+\|\d(.\d+|$)` I am able to get the desired results.

When in Snowflake running the following query, returns the correct results:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23', '\\w+\\|\\d(.\\d+|$)') AS regexp_return;
```

However when used in a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dnr.regexp_issue ()
    returns string
    language javascript
    execute as owner
    
    AS
    
    $$
    var sql_statement = `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23', '\\w+\\|\\d(.\\d+|$)') AS regexp_return;`   
    
    var query = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_statement});
    var query_res = query.execute();
    query_res.next();
    result = query_res.getColumnValue(1);
    
    return result;
    
    $$;
```

The resulting `CALL dnr.regexp_issue();` returns a `NULL` as if no matching pattern was found.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the string not need the slashes double slashed, or do that need to be double double slashed (I had the latter in shell scripts to postgresql before)

Comment: They need to be double slashed per the snowflake docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the slashed need to be double double quoted as they are going through two string parsers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE regexp_issue ()
    returns string
    language javascript
    execute as owner
    
    AS
    
    $$
    var sql_statement = `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23', '\\\\w+\\\\|\\\\d(.\\\\d+|$)') AS regexp_return;`   
    
    var query = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_statement});
    var query_res = query.execute();
    query_res.next();
    result = query_res.getColumnValue(1);
    
    return result;
    
    $$;
    
call regexp_issue();
```

gives:

```
REGEXP_ISSUE
CCC|1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Simeon's answer, you can also use `.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")` at the end of a string that with double backslashes for Snowflake. That avoids using quadruple backslashes JavaScript + Snowflake SQL escape characters. It can make for more legible strings. It would look like this:

```
 var sql_statement = `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23', '\\w+\\|\\d(.\\d+|$)') AS regexp_return;`.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```

You can also put it in two separate lines for even more clarity and a few microseconds more processing time.

```
var sql_statement = `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AAA|BBB||CCC|1.23', '\\w+\\|\\d(.\\d+|$)') AS regexp_return;`

sql_statement = sql_statement.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
```